# What does "create a dog node and sets its data field to breed" mean?

Tags: java

I'm kind of off on nodes, what are their uses in java and what does it mean to "create a dog node and sets its data field to breed"?

Comment: The word "node" could mean many things, depending on the context.  A "dog node" is most likely a "dog" object that is a "node" in some data structure.  However, this is just a guess ... because you haven't given us any context for that instruction.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little unclear as you haven't provided any context, so I'm going to assume this is an object oriented programming question. Suppose you have a `Node` class with a data field and some accessor methods that looks something like this:

```
public class Node {
    private String data;

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Here is what creating a "dog node" and setting its "data field to breed" means:

```
Node dog = new Node();
dog.setData("breed");
```